# One Xcode project contains multi Targets with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have an iOS project `X` which have several targets, these targets have different bundle IDs, APP names, APP icons, launch screens but share one pod `MyBusinessLogicPod` (which contains most business logic source code and different image resources. I define some macros to judge which target I am building for, such as `TARGET_A_MACRO`,`TARGET_B_MACRO`

```
#if defined(TARGET_A_MACRO)

static NSString *kAPPID = @"123456";
static NSInteger kChannel = 1;

#elif defined(TARGET_B_MACRO)

static NSString *kAPPID = @"789";
static NSInteger kChannel = 2;

#endif
```

**Question 1**:
How can I load different image resources in podspec file according to `X`'s target,  Different targets do share this pod, but we don't wanna pack Target B's resource into Target A's bundle.

**Question 2**:
Is it possible that we do `pod install` once, and all targets' macro are set, so I can build different targets directly. My Podfile didn't work.

**Question 3**:
Any better solutions for my scenario？

My podfile:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

def shared_pods
  pod 'AFNetworking'
  pod 'Masonry'
  pod 'MyBusinessLogicPod'
end

target 'TargetA' do
  shared_pods
end

target 'TargetB' do
  shared_pods
end

post_install do |installer|
  
  project_path = Pathname.pwd.children.select { |pn| pn.extname == '.xcodeproj' }.first
  puts "Main Target xcodeproj path: #{project_path}"
  xcproj_objc = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)
  
  xcproj_objc.targets.each do |xctarget|
    
    puts "xctarget.name: #{xctarget.name}"
    if xctarget.name == 'TargetA'
      puts "xctarget.name1: #{xctarget.name}"

      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          if config.name == 'Release'
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'TARGET_A_MACRO=1']
          elsif config.name == 'Debug'
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'TARGET_A_MACRO=1']
          end
          end
        end
    elsif xctarget.name = 'TargetB'
       puts "xctarget.name2: #{xctarget.name}"
       installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if config.name == 'Release'
              config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'TARGET_B_MACRO=1']
            elsif config.name == 'Debug'
              config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'TARGET_B_MACRO=1']
            end
            end
          end
          
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Q1: Why can't you do it in Xcode instead pod file? You can set any image resource for every target. Q2: I don't understand what you need to do. Any other info will be helpful.

Comment: @DiegoJiménez We have several teams to develop one big APP, and we don't have the permission to the project `X`, we only provide pod  to them. A lot of big companies develop super Apps like this, it's quite popular in my country.

Comment: Well, I have worked for banking apps, really big ones too, the difference is that we had access to the project config, and our targets environments are defined in the project not in the pod. Sorry dude.